# How to build proper OTP boxes in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I need to build this OTP component.

[image]

At first it seems to be very simple in terms of design, we just have create 4 boxes and use 1 TextInput component for each.

But the issue with this approach is that user will have to tap every box and write the number.

So, I thought of another idea where we have to use only 1 TextInput component and cover it with a view such that 4 windows are formed through which text could be seen.

Although the approach seems to be fine but I don't understand how do I write code for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use  this package in my project https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input